# How to write an 'anyOf' statement in JSON?

Tags: python, json, schema

I'm trying to output JSON that will be accepted by the following structure in my schema.  The relevant portion of the schema is here:

```
"special_needs": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "input-type":"checkbox",
                    "label": "learning differences",
                    "help-block":"please check all that apply",
                    "anyOf": {
                        "category_0": {
                            "main": { "enum": ["learning"]},
                            "sub": { "enum": ["ADD/ADHD", "dyslexia", "general learning disability", "language disorder", "intellectual giftedness", "other"]}
                         },
                        "category_1": {
                            "main": { "enum": ["mental"]},
                            "sub": { "enum": ["down's syndrome", "asperger's syndrome", "autism", "other"]}
                        },
                        "category_2": {
                            "main": { "enum": ["behavioral"]}
                        },
                        "category_3": {
                            "main": { "enum": ["medical"]},
                            "sub": { "enum": ["diabetes", "allergies", "eating disorders", "chronic illness", "other"]}
                        },
                        "category_4": {
                            "main": { "enum": ["physical"]},
                            "sub": { "enum": ["blind", "deaf", "cerebral palsy", "other"]}
                        }
                    }
                },
```

I've tried to write JSON that will be accepted using the following, which should default to an empty array and therefore be accepted by the validator.

```
main = row.get('main', [])
sub = row.get('sub',[])
special_needs = dict(main = main, sub = sub)
```

But get this error:

```
Failed validating u'type' in schema[u'properties'][u'definitions'][u'additionalProperties'][u'properties'][u'properties'][u'additionalProperties'][u'properties'][u'anyOf']:
    {u'items': {u'$ref': u'#'}, u'minItems': 1, u'type': u'array'}

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 76, in check_schema
    raise SchemaError.create_from(error)
jsonschema.exceptions.SchemaError: {'category_4': {'main': {'enum': ['physical']}, 'sub': {'enum': ['blind', 'deaf', 'cerebral palsy', 'other']}}, 'category_3': {'main': {'enum': ['medical']}, 'sub': {'enum': ['diabetes', 'allergies', 'eating disorders', 'chronic illness', 'other']}}, 'category_2': {'main': {'enum': ['behavioral']}}, 'category_1': {'main': {'enum': ['mental']}, 'sub': {'enum': ["down's syndrome", "asperger's syndrome", 'autism', 'other']}}, 'category_0': {'main': {'enum': ['learning']}, 'sub': {'enum': ['ADD/ADHD', 'dyslexia', 'general learning disability', 'language disorder', 'intellectual giftedness', 'other']}}} is not of type u'array'

On instance[u'definitions']['person'][u'properties']['special_needs'][u'anyOf']:
    {'category_0': {'main': {'enum': ['learning']},
                    'sub': {'enum': ['ADD/ADHD',
                                     'dyslexia',
                                     'general learning disability',
                                     'language disorder',
                                     'intellectual giftedness',
                                     'other']}},
     'category_1': {'main': {'enum': ['mental']},
                    'sub': {'enum': ["down's syndrome",
                                     "asperger's syndrome",
                                     'autism',
                                     'other']}},
     'category_2': {'main': {'enum': ['behavioral']}},
     'category_3': {'main': {'enum': ['medical']},
                    'sub': {'enum': ['diabetes',
                                     'allergies',
                                     'eating disorders',
                                     'chronic illness',
                                     'other']}},
     'category_4': {'main': {'enum': ['physical']},
                    'sub': {'enum': ['blind',
                                     'deaf',
                                     'cerebral palsy',
                                     'other']}}}
logout
```

What should I write in order to get the correct JSON?

---

New code:

```
main = row.get('main', [])
sub = row.get('sub',[])
category_0 = dict(main = main, sub = sub)
category_1 = dict(main = main, sub = sub)
category_2 = dict(main = main, sub = sub)
category_3 = dict(main = main, sub = sub)
category_4 = dict(main = main, sub = sub)

special_needs = dict(category_0 = category_0, category_1 = category_1, category_2 = category_2, category_3 = category_3, category_4 = category_4)
```

New output:

```
'special_needs': {'category_0': {'main': [], 'sub': []},
                    'category_1': {'main': [], 'sub': []},
                    'category_2': {'main': [], 'sub': []},
                    'category_3': {'main': [], 'sub': []},
                    'category_4': {'main': [], 'sub': []}},
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to specify one of the categories:

```
...
special_needs = {'category_n': {'main': main, 'sub': sub}}
```

Comment: Tried and it's outputting JSON that looks right. But the validator is still not liking it. I've updated the question to include the updated code + output.